# Android Checking webview content in background

Tags: android, background, webview, notifications

Since weeks I've been trying to create an activity that checks the HTML content of a webview (i managed it thanks to answers i found on this website)
What I didn't manage is to make this activity run in background without the user could know it's running
In background it should check the content of this page and when it change, a notification must be sent.

I'd like to know if it is possible and if someone has managed it, it would be very helpful.
Thanks by advance

Comment: Have you tried using alarmManager to start a service that downloads the HTML? For example, in this web is explained how to update an app every 30 seconds. Is this what you want?: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: Maybe my bad english made me talk not clearly. I've managed to make an activity run in background too but not with the specifities i've talked about before : check the html content from a webview. I must check the content of a webpage, and to me the only way is via a webview, but i'm not sure i can place a webview in a serivce, can I ?

Comment: So, you want to parse the HTML and find some content that is inside it? Maybe something like this? http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/using-xpath-and-html-cleaner-to-parse-html-xml/

Answer (score 0):

Check with Activity life cycle. This will Help You 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Maybe my bad english made me talk not clearly.
I've managed to make an activity run in background too but not with the specifities i've talked about before : check the html content from a webview. I must check the content of a webpage, and to me the only way is via a webview, but i'm not sure i can place a webview in a serivce, can I ?

Comment: No You cant place a webview in service. service doesn't have an UI.

Comment: A service doesn't have a UI, but @AndroidRookieOfTheYearInchalla wants to notify the user of changes on the website for the URL.  You could do a `diff` to detect changes in the HTML body, or parse the HTML and detect changes in a specific node like a div.